# Input string error when posting for next set of data

Tags: c#, web-scraping, fiddler

The other day I had my scraper working very well, when I realized that I wasn't getting enough records, I decided to search by postal code and had to change some of my code. The first POST and RESPONSE goes off without a hitch, but when I post to get the next page of results it fails on the Response.

the starting code is...

```
public void StartScrape()
{
    List<string> a = lstPostalCodes();
    for (int i = 0; i <= lstPostalCodes().Count; i++)
    {
        b = a[i];
        FirstRequestResponse(b);

        if (GoBackToStartSearch == "CONTINUEON")
            StartNextRequest(GetViewState(ResponseData));
        else
        {
            WriteDataToFile(ResponseData);
            FinalClean();
        }
    }
}
```

The method that I am calling is StartNextRequest. In the StartNextRequest method is

```
private void GetResults(HttpWebRequest wr)
{
    using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(wr.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
    {
        // Add response/results to string
        ResponseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    string strFind = "<li id='nextdisabled'>";

    if (ResponseData.Contains(strFind)) GoBackToStartSearch = "BACKTOSTART";
    else
        GoBackToStartSearch = "CONTINUEON";
}
```

The error that its throwing is saying that the

> Input string was not in correct format

and pointing at the using (StreamReader...)

I have gotten other errors that I seem to fix, but then it creates another error which has to do with waiting for bytes to be written. I'm using Fiddler2 to give me more info on the errors, the headers are pretty much the same, I'm not seeing much of a difference, other than 1 being a request and the other a response.

I have no idea on why its saying that, I have stepped through the working code that I wrote to scrape all the data results, and compared the two. Everything looks the same. The values are all the same.

Any ideas on where I should look to fix this?

Comment: Split out that nested line into individual variables/statements, then see which one of them is actually throwing?

Comment: @EricLaw, I'm going to break the code down soon and give that a shot. Its weird though that scraping the sites data results it worked properly but as soon as I changed it up to use postal codes it fails, not on the first post and response but when it'd going to the next page of results. I'll post with an update

Comment: @EricLaw, I changed things around and that error is fixed and the new error that it throws is the "Cannot close stream until all bytes are written"

Comment: Found what was causing the errors, it was in my postData variable. I looked over everything and seen that I was passing another variable with the post that was screwing up my ViewState for the next page.